# Execute MySQL Trigger only when specific NEW value exists

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, mariadb

I want to execute my MySQL(MariaDB) Trigger only when a specific value in NEW exists and is not null.

How can I wrap my Trigger in an if clause that checks if the new insert contains a value for lets say `Name`. So if theres a new insert or update query which don't set the field `Name` I don't want to run the trigger.

I've tried

```
IF NEW.Name IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
 ...
END
```

But it doesn't work.

My actual trigger code does properly use the values from NEW.

My trigger looks like this.

```
INSERT INTO Produkte (Textilkennzeichen, Produktnummer, Bestand, createdAt, updatedAt)
VALUES (NEW.Textilkennzeichen, NEW.Produktnummer,
@Bestand := (
    SELECT IFNULL(SUM(`Anzahl`), 0)
    FROM Eintragungen
    WHERE Produziert = true
    AND Textilkennzeichen = NEW.Textilkennzeichen
    AND Produktnummer = NEW.Produktnummer
)
-
((
    SELECT IFNULL(SUM(`Anzahl`), 0) 
    FROM Eintragungen
    WHERE Verkauf = true
    AND Textilkennzeichen = NEW.Textilkennzeichen
    AND Produktnummer = NEW.Produktnummer
)
+
(
    SELECT IFNULL(SUM(`Anzahl`), 0)
    FROM Eintragungen
    WHERE Schenkung = true
    AND Textilkennzeichen = NEW.Textilkennzeichen
    AND Produktnummer = NEW.Produktnummer
)
+
(
    SELECT @amount_r := IFNULL(SUM(`Anzahl`), 0)
    FROM Eintragungen
    WHERE Reklamation = true
    AND Textilkennzeichen = NEW.Textilkennzeichen
    AND Produktnummer = NEW.Produktnummer
)), NOW(), NOW())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Bestand = @Bestand
```

Comment: Why not just put the `IF` in the `BEGIN`/`END` block, making it part of the trigger?

Comment: The correct syntax for if is IF...THEN...ENDIF;

Comment: @GordonLinoff I Dont actually write `BEGIN`/`END` in the DB application I use. I start with `INSERT` directly but if I put the `IF NEW.Name IS NOT NULL` right at the beginning it doesn't work either.

Comment: @P.Salmon I can't use `IF` `THEN` `END IF` either. I get the following error.

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 37. I'm using Sequel Pro to manage my DB.

Comment: Please add your full trigger code and how your are creating trigger(wizard mysqlworkbench) - nb my comment was just that not an answer.

Comment: *I want to execute my MySQL(MariaDB) Trigger only when* This is absolutely impossible - trigger fires always when its action is performed.

Comment: @Akina yeah thats worded badly on my side, I just want to execute the code when the condition is met. Added my whole trigger code.

Comment: *My trigger looks like this* This is **NOT** a trigger. This is common UPDATE query.

Comment: @P.Salmon added.

Comment: Do not use variable. Use `VALUES()` function.

Comment: Trigger code starts create trigger..for each row...end

Comment: @Akina I'm using Sequel Pro to add the trigger therefore I don't have to write the actual trigger part.

Comment: @P.Salmon I'm using Sequel Pro to add the trigger.

Comment: Either you ask something about MySQL - if so then post MySQL code, or you ask something about Sequel Pro - if so then do not refer to MySQL.

Comment: @Akina The problem is not about Sequel Pro though. The trigger works like that, I just want to add the IF part.

Comment: You have failed to tell us what kind of trigger (before insert,after insert,before update,after update) and the table on which the trigger will fire.

Comment: @P.Salmon The trigger does fire after insert and update. The table is called Eintragungen.

Comment: You cannot "wrap trigger". But you may wrap trigger's body code. I.e. it must wrap your UPDATE query only.

Comment: @Akina yeah thats what I want to do, sry I've worded it badly. How can I wrap the UPDATE though.

Comment: You don't wrap the update you wrap the entire insert..

Comment: `IF NEW.Name IS NOT NULL THEN {your INSERT query}; END IF;`

Comment: @Akina Thank you! The problem was I forgot the semicolon at the end of the insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code should be

```
if something then
   insert ...;
endif;
```

presumably your ide makes the create..for each row begin...end

so you end up with
create trigger..
for each row
begin
if something then
insert ...;
endif;
end